# How to use mediapipe graphs like the mediapipe API-s

Tags: android, mediapipe

I'm struggling to understand how am I meant to interact with the "graph" and "calculator" stuff from the [mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) library. More specifically, I'd like to write some Android code that uses landmarks from the holistic (pose + hands in my case) solution, with the final goal of writing a `flutter` application that compiles both for Android and iOS.

I've managed to build a few of the sample apps (thanks to `docker`), and I think I *roughly* understand what the graphs do. However, I don't understand how to interact with them from within the code. The [Hello World!](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/hello_world_android.html) for  Android tutorial doesn't really explain this. There are examples that include this type of behaviour (e.g. [here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/posetrackinggpu/MainActivity.java)), but I don't really know where is all the required information coming from (e.g. how would I find out the right functions and string constants to get holistic landmarks?)

For example, in Python I could get data via something like `holistic.process(image).pose_landmarks`, and then compute e.g. position or angle of hips. And as far as I can see there are some similar Android API-s available, although not for all solutions - including holistic. So what if I don't want to wait for the API-s development, and want to use the graphs instead? That part is not so clear.

As a bonus, please do feel free to drop any links which further explain/document the "graph" and "calculator" stuff I've mentioned earlier, as I've not used anything like this before and find it a little difficult to google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised there are docs available: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/framework_concepts/framework_concepts.html

Not sure how I've missed this...